# Bash script to sepate and move the date to the front of the file name

Tags: bash

I have a thousand avi and jpg mixed files that have been named so

```
01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.avi
01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.jpg
01 09 55 PM 26-03-2019-A.avi
01 09 55 PM 26-03-2019-A.jpg
```

I wish to place the date first like so

```
27-03-2019-A 01 09 52 PM.avi
```

How can I do that please?

Comment: This is about Puppy Linux as per [OP’s comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130079/bash-script-to-sepate-and-move-the-date-to-the-front-of-the-file-name/1130081#comment1871671_1130081).

Answer (score 0):

With `file-rename` from the [`rename` [image: Install rename]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rename) package:

```
file-rename -n 's/(.*PM) (.*-A)/$2 $1/' *
```

This prints the changes first, remove the `-n` flag to actually perform the action. The `s`ubstitute expression captures the first string ending in “PM” and the next ending in “-A” (without the space between them) in two groups and replaces them with themselves in reverse order and a space between them. Note that `*` takes *every* file in the current directory, change it if you want to match a subset, e.g. `*-A.*` for every file whose name contains “-A.”.

If you don’t want to install anything you can do the renaming with `bash` and `mv`:

```
for i in *; do
  echo mv -i "$i" "${i:12:12} ${i:0:11}.${i/*.}"
done
```

This loops over the files printing the `mv` commands for the renaming, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files. It uses [`bash` Parameter Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion) to get the relevant strings from the input file name.

#### Example run

Note that I have `rename` linked to `file-rename` using the alternatives system.

```
$ touch "01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.avi"
$ rename -n 's/(.*PM) (.*-A)/$2 $1/' *
rename(01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.avi, 27-03-2019-A 01 09 52 PM.avi)
$ rename 's/(.*PM) (.*-A)/$2 $1/' *
$ ls
27-03-2019-A 01 09 52 PM.avi
$ rm 27-03-2019-A\ 01\ 09\ 52\ PM.avi
$ touch "01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.avi"
$ for i in *;do echo mv "$i" "${i:12:12} ${i:0:11}.${i/*.}";done
mv 01 09 52 PM 27-03-2019-A.avi 27-03-2019-A 01 09 52 PM.avi
$ for i in *;do mv "$i" "${i:12:12} ${i:0:11}.${i/*.}";done
$ ls
27-03-2019-A 01 09 52 PM.avi
```

Comment: That does not work for me . Im on a Puppy Linux O/S . I notice it does not recognise the -n switch either. I removed it and tried on a test directory but no go.

Comment: @April I guess you don’t use perl rename. Sorry, but this definitely works on Ubuntu. Puppy Linux is off topic here, you should ask on [unix.se] instead.

Comment: Its close enough to give me a lead though.Thanks
You sure it works  ??

Comment: The example is (of course!) not just written up, but rather actual output from a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The package name may very well be different in your distro, e.g. `perl-rename` or `prename`.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.